# How to convert multiple newlines in mako template to one newline?

Tags: python, mako

I am using `mako template` with `python` and trying to generate a text file by using a list from `python` script. A part of code is shown below which is causing problem.

```
% for COMPNAME in tpdob.scalar_modi:
    ${COMPNAME[0]} ${COMPNAME[1]} ${COMPNAME[2]} ${COMPNAME[3]}
% endfor
```

I am using this code and the output is horrible. 
Here, I have many lists in `scalar_modi` and I am printing them one by one (each list has 4 values). But the problem is, there are so many newlines that gets printed making the output text file look ugly.
I searched on net, but unable to find the required solution.
Can you please help me out with this?

Comments on output:

With `${COMPNAME[0]} ${COMPNAME[1]} ${COMPNAME[2]} ${COMPNAME[3]}` , I am getting:
1 42 gzb dli

14 23 tpty sre

32 55 puri ald

When using `${COMPNAME[0]} ${COMPNAME[1]} ${COMPNAME[2]} ${COMPNAME[3]} \`, gives :
11 42 gzb dli14 23 tpty sre32 55 puri ald

And I want it like:
11 42 gzb dli
14 23 tpty sre
32 55 puri ald

And when using `if-else` conditions, I am getting even more than 2 `newlines`. Can anyone please help me with this. I am unable to find the solution in its documentation also :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same problem, looks like a bug in Mako Templates for Windows. Providing the template as a string instead of a file reference (as shown below) solved the problem.

```
with open('code.template') as f:
    templateStr = f.read()
template = mako.template.Template(templateStr)
```

Comment: Bug link: https://github.com/sqlalchemy/mako/issues/150

Answer (score 2):

Old topic but I just found out a better approach using the preprocessor kwarg:

```
tpl_lookup = TemplateLookup(directories=['./templates'], output_encoding='utf-8', module_directory='./tmp', preprocessor=[lambda x: x.replace("\r\n", "\n")])
```